# Wordpress post thumbnails

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to stop wordpress resizing images?

I already have in the functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 235, 419 );
add_image_size( 'single-post-thumbnail', 235, 419 );
```

Still doesn't work, when I upload a post thumbnail resizes it to some crazy sizes which I don't want..Any way to get this working?

//The resized image is 235x198 it should be  235x419that's the size of the image that I'm uploading

//SOLVED with the_post_thumbnail("large");

Comment: What are the sizes? Try having a look in your WP-Admin settings to see if there's a maximum size specified. I know WordPress references different sizes with names such as 'large', 'thumbnail', 'small' so they must be resized internally during upload at some stage.

Comment: 235x198 it should be  235x419that's the size of the image that I'm uploading

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's scaling the image! Pass a third argument as `true` so that images are cropped to the exact size.